# Extract single URL from webpage by scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape a website such as the one below. In the footer there are a bunch of links of their social media out of which the LinkedIn URL is the point of focus for me. Is there a way to fish out only that link maybe using regex or any other libraries available in Python.

This is what I have tried so far -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.southcoast.org/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text,"html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
 print(link.get('href'))
```

But I'm fetching all the URLs instead of the one I'm looking for.

Note: I'd appreciate a dynamic code which I can use for other sites as well.

Thanks in advance for you suggestion/help.
[image]

Comment: Note: we'd appreciate if you showed us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of text and instead post your code using the appropriate code tags (e.g. `{}` button).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @JanWilamowski. Edited the post with the code I tried.

Comment: You aren't doing any filtering of the links. Have you looked at the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the re filtering part. Let me check that out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to use `css selectors` and look for string `linkedin.com/company/` in values of `href` attributes:

```
soup.select_one('a[href*="linkedin.com/company/"]')['href']
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.southcoast.org/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")

# single (first) link
link = e['href'] if(e := soup.select_one('a[href*="linkedin.com/company/"]')) else None
# multiple links
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('a[href*="linkedin.com/company/"]')]
```

Comment: Hi @hedgehog, thanks for your suggestion. May I get some clarity on the if statement especially "if(**e :=** ...)" part.

Comment: The statment checks if element exists before calling its attribute to avoid errors, it uses walrus operator to make it a bit shorter